# What kind of character does a person who makes loud exclamations have?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, personality

Here, I am trying to find an adjective to describe a (relatively poor) person who is open but attracts a lot of attention (not attention-seeking though). As an example, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLX2tAPy0jU).

I’ve thought of *exuberant* but I feel that it reflects energy and excitement in youth rather than the kind of personality you might find in the Nurse in *Romeo and Juliet*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The adjective *boisterous* might well answer. OED offers “Abounding in rough but good-natured activity bordering upon excess, such as proceeds from unchecked exuberance of spirits”; [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boisterous) makes it “very noisy and active in a lively way.”

Comment: I think that boisterous was the word I was looking for since it has connotations of noise.

Answer (score 4):

*[Rambunctious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rambunctious)* is a relatively new North American expression that parallels boisterous:

> adjective
>
> 1. difficult to control or handle; wildly boisterous:
> 2. turbulently active and noisy:

Comment: That's a beautiful word--but I think it's English, too. At least, it is [related to "rumbustious", according to M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rambunctious)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is **ebullient**:

> ebullience -
>   [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ebullience)
>
> Bubbly, loud, and enthusiastic: ebullience means "the quality of being
>   cheerful and full of energy."

synonyms:

> exuberant, buoyant, cheerful, joyful, cheery, merry, sunny, breezy,
>   jaunty, light-hearted, in high spirits, high-spirited, exhilarated,
>   elated, euphoric, jubilant, animated, sparkling, effervescent,
>   vivacious, enthusiastic, irrepressible

[Google Dictionary as was]

Answer (score 1):

I would describe the way the woman in the video expresses herself as [emphatic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emphatic):

> - speaking or acting in a forceful way.
> - forceful and definite in expression or action.

(from W-W)

Comment: Although the woman does speak forcefully, I could describe, say David Cameron or Barack Obama as speaking forcefully. But still, a great additional adjective to consider +1

Answer (score 1):

You can say the woman is

- "rumbustious" ("Uncontrollably exuberant" - [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rumbustious))
- "rumbustiously outspoken"
- "rumbustiously spontaneous"

Brian Donovan's answer, "boisterous", is a single word and fits better what you are looking for, though.